# Using iter on a list with a default value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to be able to do this:

```
foo = ['a', 'b']
bar = iter(foo, "default")
val = next(bar)
while val !== "default":
    print(val)
    val = next(bar)
```

However, that doesn't work because of the second parameter when creating the iter object. I see from the docs that this changes how the first value is used:

> Return an iterator object. The first argument is interpreted very differently depending on the presence of the second argument. Without a second argument, object must be a collection object which supports the iteration protocol (the `__iter__() method`), or it must support the sequence protocol (the `__getitem__() method` with integer arguments starting at 0). If it does not support either of those protocols, TypeError is raised. If the second argument, sentinel, is given, then object must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call object with no arguments for each call to its `__next__() method`; if the value returned is equal to sentinel, StopIteration will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

But I don't see a pythonic way to do what I want without resorting to `try/catch` (aka this)

```
bar = iter(foo)
try:
    while True:
        print(next(bar))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: So why are you not using a `for` loop, exactly?

Comment: Because the codeflow needs to skip over N iterations next time. I don't want to visit every element (but which and how many elements to skip are determined in the loop body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pythonic way would usually be to use a for loop:

```
for val in foo:
    print(val)
```

or if that doesn't work, put the default value in the `next` call instead of attaching it to the iterator itself:

```
bar = iter(foo)
val = next(bar, "default")
```

If you really want to do this in the iterator, you can use `itertools.chain` to chain your iterator with an infinite sequence of your sentinel value:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
bar = chain(foo, repeat("default"))
```

To skip over elements inside a for loop, you could:

```
bar = iter(foo)
for val in bar:
    if_some_condition():
        next(bar) # skips over the next iteration of the loop
```

Comment: So, the reason I'm not using a normal for loop is that I need to be able to skip elements, as determined by the body of the function. The reason for not wanting to use exceptions is that this is in a (actually measured) hot loop in the code, and so I was looking for a non-exception based way.

Comment: @AnilRedshift: You can skip elements in a for loop. If you loop over an iterator, explicitly `next`-ing the iterator inside the loop body will cause the loop to skip over the element returned by the explicit `next` call.

Comment: Can you give an example? What do I `next`?

Comment: @AnilRedshift: If you want to skip the current object, use `continue`, if you want to skip the next objects, I would use a variable `skip_n = 1` and do this: `if skip_n > 0: skip_n -= 1; continue` at the start of your loop.

Comment: Or alternative (as user2357112 suggests): `foo_iterator = iter(foo); for val in foo_iterator: if want_to_skip_next_item: next(foo_iterator)`.

Comment: Right. Must be a long day. I'll merge this with @user2357112's post and call it good. Thanks!

Comment: instead of next, to skip elements inside a loop, use [continue](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement)